# Is it a bad practice to use $filter inside a custom filter?

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom filter that shows the name of the month given the month number

```
angular.module('porteApp')
  .filter('monthName', function($filter) {
    return function (number) {
      return $filter('date')(new Date(2015, number), 'MMMM');
    }
  });
```

It works but feels wrong somehow, is it a bad practice?

```
{{0 | monthName}}
> january
```

Comment: In fact month number `1´ is Februari in Javascript ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No at all, feel free to use it, while you are not:
 - writing unreadable or unmaintainable code
 - writing unsecure or vulnerable code

Everything else do what you want if it save your time and do what needed